# how to configure Pre-commit hook in windows for some specific values (BugID)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, hook, pre-commit

I want to integrate TeamID in log messages using pre-commit hook.Currently ,we are not using any kind of bug-tracking tool.
I have someTeamIDs and want User to enter teamID (This teamID should be valid ) .
I Have tried using property of svn for Bugtraq but dont know how to validate those TeamIDs.Can I compare these IDS with some excel sheet entries.

Please note we don't want to  integrate a whole bug tracking system with SVN.Just want to compare a handful of TeamIDS with ID entered in log message.Any sugestions please?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `svnlook log` command to examine the commit message of the transaction in your pre-commit hook. You will need some pattern to delimit where the TeamID is in the log message. Filter the TeamID out of the log message.

I suggest that you store your "excel sheet" as a plain .txt file instead listing all the valid team IDs. Or, you could still use a spreadsheet, but store it as CSV or some other more easily parsed format. Then, commit this file to SVN. Use `svnlook cat` to compare the captured TeamID from the log message, to the file containing valid team IDs. Return a failure code if the log message TeamID is not contained in the list of valid IDs.